# Barcode Scanner App Using ZXing Xamarin for iOS hits null reference error in Application Class

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, zxing

I need a smartphone based Barcode/QRcode scanner app for my company and it has to work on iPhone and Android, but mostly iPhone.  I decided to give Xamarin Forms a shot and it worked perfectly for Android, but took some serious legwork to get the app to even show up on an iPhone.  I finally got it to open on the iPhone, but when I click on the scan button it throws up
    Unhandled Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object`
```

in the Application class on UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace QRNatives.iOS
{
    public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
}
```

I haven't been programming for too long, but it seems that normally null reference errors are fairly easy to trace.  However, I can not see where the problem is actually happening with this one.  I suspect the problem is in AppDelegate.cs, though nothing really sticks out to me.

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace QRNatives.iOS
{
// The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
// User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
// application events from iOS.
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
}
```

Just for more info, here is what I am using for the QrScanningService.cs for linking the iOS to the shared interface data.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using QRNatives.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ZXing.Mobile;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(QRNatives.iOS.Services.QrScanningService))]

namespace QRNatives.iOS.Services
{
class QrScanningService
{
    public class QrCodeScanningService : IQrScanningServies
    {
        public async Task<string> ScanAsync()
        {
            var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
            var scanResults = await scanner.Scan();

            return scanResults.Text;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have searched a number of old posts were this issue came up, but none of the ones I've read had any real answers to the problem.  Has anyone had any experience successfully using ZXing with Xamarin for iOS?  Or does anyone have any suggestions about how else I could track down where the error is actually coming from?  I've been stuck on this for a while so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I actually found out that my problem is happening in the button click event handler.  It is not accessing the camera on the iPhone for some reason and therefore leaves the result null.  The line...... var scanner = DependencyService.Get<IQrScanningServies>(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance); is not opening the camera like it does on android.

Comment: So, can you show  the related code in `var scanner = DependencyService.Get<IQrScanningServies>(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance);`  where the problem happens? Did you give  your app permission to access the camera?

Comment: Jack Hua I was able to add permission for the camera.  I went into the Info.plist file by opening it with notebook and added....... 

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera acess to scan barcodes</string>

Visual Studio didn't give me the option to add it within the IDE.  After doing that it accessed the camera just fine.  I did have to restart the phone and re-enter my id before it would connect to my rest API, but as of this morning I have it completely working on both Android and Apple.

Comment: Ok, so you solved your problem by add `camera permission` in your app. Also, you can edit the `info.plist` in Visual Studio. I will post an answer to show you how to do it. Please accept it so that we can help more people with same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a bit.  Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To** access `camera` in iPhone, you should add permission in `info.plist`:

```
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>      
 <string>Camera acess to scan barcodes</string>
```

**To** edit `info.plist` inside Visual Studio:

Right click `info.plist` and choose `open with`, you can choose `Generic PList Editor` or `XML editor`(whatever you want) to edit it.

More permissions:

Refer to : [infoplist-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/infoplist-reference)

Comment: Also, so everyone knows... if you run into any other permission issues you need to get the UDID number from your phone and use that to add the device to your apple developer profile and then after you've done that you need to add that device to your Development Provisioning Profile and then download that new profile and open it on the Mac computer your phone is connected to.  Took me a while to figure this all out myself.